# Using my own python module in Azure Pyspark, the module reads and prepares the data

Tags: python-3.x, azure, pyspark, azure-storage

My jupyter notebook, reads a module I created, in Jupyter I add

```
sc.addPyFile('wasb:///HdiNotebooks/PySpark/project/read_test_data.py')
```

and it loads the module ok,

However, my "py" file, opens the data as:

```
data_file= open('wasb:///example/data/fruits.txt', 'rU') 
to prepare it and do different calculations.
```

However, I get the following error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wasb:///example/data/fruits.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wasb:///example/data/fruits.txt'
```

If I tried to create a dataframe with the same data in jupyter I run

```
df=sqlContext.read.csv('wasb:///example/data/fruits.txt',header='true', inferSchema='true')
```

And I dont get any errors. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Python API [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) does not support the `wasb` protocol for HDInsight DFS based on Azure Blob Storage.

If you want to directly read the file on HDInsight without pyspark, the only way is using Azure Storage SDK for Python to do it with `account_name` & `account_key` of Azure Blob Storage Account for HDInsight like the [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2015/10/02/using-azure-sdk-for-python/) said, and please refer to the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage) for Azure Storage in Python.

Hope it helps.